# Gatling - Check if response body string key is certain value

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a scenario in Gatling and I want to check if the response body value maps to an error string. The response is a 400:

```
{"error": "ERROR_1"}
```

The check is failing with a compilation error:

```
 http("Some Request")
  .put("/endpoint")
  .asJson
  .check(jsonPath("$.error") == "ERROR_1")
  .check(status.is(400))
```

Also tried saving the error as a variable

```
.check(jsonPath("$.error").saveAs("error"))
.check("${error}" == "ERROR_1")
```

And realised the `.check("${error}".is("ERROR_1"))` won't work either since .is only works for ints. The gatling docs don't explain expressions too much either https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_check#validating

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement that .is only works for ints is incorrect - and this is how you should construct this check.

Here's a working example with a passing check

```
def test : ScenarioBuilder = scenario("test")
.exec(
  http("test call")
    .post("http://httpbin.org/anything")
    .body(StringBody("""{"error": "ERROR_1"}"""))
    .check(jsonPath("$..error").is("ERROR_1"))
)
```

You can't use `==` as a gatling check needs one or more HttpChecks and `==` returns a boolean.

Comment: Beware that recursive filters are generally slower than exact paths as it requires scanning the whole tree. If you know the exact path of what you're looking for and it's simple enough, you should use it instead of `..`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.check(
      status.is(400),
      jsonPath("$.error").is("ERROR_1")
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the answers! Seems I was missing the . in .error, so this worked for me:

```
 http("Some Request")
  .put("/endpoint")
  .asJson
  .check(jsonPath("$.error").is("ERROR_1"))
  .check(status.is(400))
```